# unable to create table using subreports in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using report book in Jasper reports and in that, I have to create a Content-report (same as sub-report) containing a table.I am using JRBeanCollectionDataSource.

when I compile and run the sub-report individually, It works perfectly.
but when I run whole Report book, then it won't even print that Subreport, other sub reports will be printed as expected.

I am sure that, I am missing some minor settings. Because in report book, I am using chart, crosstab  they are working fine. but the only problem is with that table.

this is my subreport jrxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.0  -->
<!-- 2016-08-02T13:49:19 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="sub_filter_table" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="5ec68712-81e7-4231-85ad-a535169f9480">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.create.bookmarks" value="true"/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="filterTableDataset" uuid="5e16eed0-53ee-4e32-9078-a3f75f05ca4e">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
        <parameter name="filterTableDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="database" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="systemNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="channels" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="from" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="to" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="keep" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="description" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="filterTableDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <parameter name="filter_table_title" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["Filter logs"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="SITE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <summary>
        <band height="342">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="110" width="555" height="100" uuid="f7bcc7fb-0f93-41a1-96fd-a17d82997667">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.autoresize.proportional" value="true"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.autoresize.next" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="filterTableDataset" uuid="c89753d2-101b-4cbc-a23b-0c83bd725c45">
                        <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{filterTableDataSource}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                        <datasetParameter name="filterTableDataSource">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{filterTableDataSource}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{filterTableDataSource}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="73" uuid="1f2db4a6-020e-47f7-baf2-3544dcb71121">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="73" height="30" uuid="14c78a1d-169f-4a55-9a9c-754fa02fd371"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[database]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="73" height="30" uuid="4e86a802-0103-43ea-85fb-ae227412b60f"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{database}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="73" uuid="b21d7484-4645-4759-b3a1-e0dc7dc2cdf9">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="73" height="30" uuid="a74174db-9266-4a63-8571-3e6b7a5e671a"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[systemNumber]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="73" height="30" uuid="06a5dd33-40a5-48dd-93b2-ed21a86894b1"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{systemNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="73" uuid="672670d2-071a-4987-b9b5-b9ccec62ffcd">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="73" height="30" uuid="02b4645f-4e30-40f7-8229-bbb01dd3fc94"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[channels]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="73" height="30" uuid="94eb42f5-b3f2-4592-b5f7-5a4cc48f1eec"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{channels}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="68" uuid="83e9f896-849b-4d96-bde7-c35f73824100">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="68" height="30" uuid="30b2d1c9-4cd0-4358-9df9-aa7fa99c22a2"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[from]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="68" height="30" uuid="64748c55-8224-4ba2-8275-13c13a2b66a5"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{from}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="54" uuid="896e3191-2c4a-428d-a65f-658375611c01">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="54" height="30" uuid="34bfb207-d3e0-4343-8a7b-69aa6b15e881"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[to]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="54" height="30" uuid="65268f63-f9c2-487f-9de6-b6045c3f8f33"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{to}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="59" uuid="ca8721df-5260-41c3-b549-19f7478831d2">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="59" height="30" uuid="558d37f8-a6e0-49a0-948f-3a8352c014ca"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[keep]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="59" height="30" uuid="5d15ec66-40c1-4b91-b330-639783230764"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{keep}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="155" uuid="94e61aed-be5f-4d95-9342-0a4a129e7fb8">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="155" height="30" uuid="737886b1-2568-4840-8d59-b6bef0bb46ed"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[description]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="155" height="30" uuid="f451bec1-8ae6-4ee5-b4ca-fb337b5c94fb"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{description}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
            <textField bookmarkLevel="2">
                <reportElement x="140" y="20" width="170" height="30" uuid="af7d5b5d-e209-4417-9830-0994cd6d5b39"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{filter_table_title}]]></textFieldExpression>
                <anchorNameExpression><![CDATA[$P{filter_table_title}]]></anchorNameExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="436" y="46" width="100" height="30" uuid="924b35b3-34f5-47ad-b404-9483044489b2"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{SITE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

main Report-book jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.0  -->
<!-- 2016-08-02T13:50:30 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Abstract_Book" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" sectionType="Part" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30" whenResourceMissingType="Error" uuid="d2716064-8ae4-40cf-a575-33afba400e3a">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.create.bookmarks" value="true"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.book.group.cover.header" value="Cover and Table of Contents"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.book.group.cover.footer" value="Backcover"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="Name" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="XYChartDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <parameter name="tableDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <parameter name="IMAGE_DIR" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="filterTableDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <parameter name="externalDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <parameter name="REPORT_TYPE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="SITE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="CMS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="OPPORTUNITY_ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="windTableDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <group name="cover">
        <groupHeader>
            <part uuid="7aed05b9-1301-4a53-b47e-34289560bc0c">
                <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd">
                    <subreportParameter name="Name">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{Name}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="externalDataSource">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{externalDataSource}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="REPORT_TYPE">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_TYPE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="CMS">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{CMS}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="SITE">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SITE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="OPPORTUNITY_ID">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{OPPORTUNITY_ID}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="IMAGE_DIR">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{IMAGE_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"/Abstract_Book_cover.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </p:subreportPart>
            </part>
            <part evaluationTime="Report" uuid="56ab525c-754f-4f48-a52c-7cc23934be3d">
                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.bookmarks.data.source.parameter" value="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE"/>
                <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd">
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"/Abstract_Book_toc.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </p:subreportPart>
            </part>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <part uuid="88decbbe-63ad-45cc-9e03-5dadc50004d5">
                <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd">
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"/Abstract_Book_backcover.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </p:subreportPart>
            </part>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <detail>
        <part uuid="3d143dd6-5587-4c12-90f0-ff77f9d026af">
            <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd">
                <subreportParameter name="SITE">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SITE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{filterTableDataSource}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"/sub_filter_table.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </p:subreportPart>
        </part>
        <part uuid="5e668430-9acd-4835-be21-f4e2902ce33d">
            <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd">
                <subreportParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XYChartDataSource}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"/sub_chart.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </p:subreportPart>
        </part>
        <part uuid="0e5ec483-6a4d-4323-8cb8-850ca3cefe34">
            <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd">
                <subreportParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{tableDataSource}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"/sub_crosstab.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </p:subreportPart>
        </part>
        <part uuid="f4249881-1728-4f1f-8c54-75fc7725f6f6">
            <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd">
                <subreportParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{windTableDataSource}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"/sub_wind_crosstab.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </p:subreportPart>
        </part>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did minor changes on Java side.

Instead of passing a JRBeanCollectionDataSource:

```
parameters.put(FILTER_TABLE_DATA_SOURCE, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(filterList));
```

I have directly passed List as Parameter

```
parameters.put(FILTER_TABLE_DATA_SOURCE, filterList);
```

**Master report**

Create a Parameters like following

```
<parameter name="FILTER_TABLE_DATA_SOURCE" class="java.util.List"/>
```

Select the sub-report on MasterReport  and Go to Properties of subreport and set Datasource Expression as following:
and it will set $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{FILTER_TABLE_DATA_SOURCE})
```

**Sub Report**

Firstly, I made a mistake by placing a table in Summary band.

> Table should always be in Detail band

because fields inside table need to be iterated, that what detail band does.

create table as usual with fields which are in that List , but remember to use `*$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}*`  as JRDatasource expression